# List of TCS conferences and workshops

Tags: soft-question, big-list, conferences

I would like to ask for help in compiling a list of as many TCS-related conferences and workshops as possible.  My main motivation for doing this is to plan possible blog coverage of more theory venues -- finding correspondents attending these events who would be willing to write either brief or in-depth blog entries about events they are attending.  Beyond that, I hope a list like this would give everyone a better sense of the lay of the theory land.

I'll seed the question with an answer containing a few "obvious" conferences.  Please feel free to edit my answer and/or post additional answers of your own.

> Standard abbreviation of conference, name of conference, subject matter, any additional notes.

Intended as community wiki.

Comment: Now it is CW. But I am not sure it is a good use of site. (IIRC, I asked something similar last year. But people generally didn't think that was a good question. We ended up deleting it, IIRC.)

Comment: +1 - I've wanted to ask this for a long time but didn't for the reason that Kaveh mentioned. Now that you have, I vote strongly in favor of keeping it.

Comment: I think it could be a useful resource. The only problem might be if people try to rank the conferences or if we get debate over if a certain conference is in-scope or not.

Comment: I believe most people would know already, but DMANET is a great resource for upcoming conferences and workshops. Of course, its area of coverage is a bit broader than TCS, but I would definitely call it CS-centered than math-centered.

Comment: My suggestion is that this should be structured like the P vs NPC post. In that there's one master "accepted" answer that maintains the union of all other answers posted in other comments.

Comment: @Suresh: Sounds good.

Comment: I was thinking on something like this with my previous question in meta (http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1263/using-the-blog-for-job-posts-and-conference-announcements). Is there any chance to have a direct link to this question from anywhere on the site?

Comment: We can add it to the FAQ, but that's not the best. I think you mean something like a set of 'highlighted' questions. I don't know if we can actually do that, and a meta question to that effect might draw attention from SE

Comment: @Marcos: One possibility is that we could create a page on the community blog once the list stabilizes here.  I've started a meta thread to discuss static blog pages here: http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1297/pages-for-the-community-blog

Comment: **mod note**: related previous [question](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/386/complexity-theory-conferences) and [meta-discussion](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/56/are-list-questions-such-as-about-conferences-on-topic). Removed the answers from the old one (which are already listed here), merged the older one with this one, removed the comments coming from the older one.

Comment: Microsoft Research actually did this listing of conference here: http://academic.research.microsoft.com/RankList?entitytype=3&topDomainID=2&subDomainID=0&last=0&start=1&end=100.

Comment: The merit is all Claire Matthieu's (see her blog: http://teachingintrotocs.blogspot.com/2011/09/conference-citations.html).

Answer (score 93, accepted):

**GENERAL**:

- STOC, [ACM Symposium on the Theory of Computing](http://www.sigact.org/stoc.html)
- FOCS, [IEEE Symposium on Foundations of Computer Science](http://ieee-focs.org/)
- ICALP [EATCS International Colloquium on Automata, Languages and Programming](http://www.eatcs.org/index.php/international-colloquium)
  (A: algorithms, complexity, B: logic, semantics,  automata)
- FOSSACS, [Foundations of Software Science and Computation Structures](http://www.etaps.org/2014/fossacs14)
- STACS, [Symposium on Theoretical Aspects of Computer Science](http://www.stacs-conf.org/)
- MFCS, [Mathematical Foundations of Computer Science](http://ist.ac.at/mfcs13/)
- FSTTCS, [Foundations of Software Technology and Theoretical Computer Science](http://www.fsttcs.org.in/)
- COCOON, [Computing and Combinatorics Conference](http://www.cs.zju.edu.cn/algo/cocoon2013/)
- ITCS, [Innovations in Theoretical Computer Science](http://itcs2013.cs.berkeley.edu/)
- CSR, [Computer Science in Russia](http://csr2013.urfu.ru/)
- ISAAC, [International Symposium on Algorithms and Computation](http://www.dais.is.tohoku.ac.jp/%7Etokuyama/ISAAC/isaacweb.html)
- TAMC, [Theory and Applications of Models of Computation](http://www.cs.hku.hk/tamc2013/)
- COCOA, [Conference on Combinatorial Optimization and Applications](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/%7Eghlin/COCOA2013/)
- FM, [Formal Methods](http://www.fmeurope.org/)
- FCT, [Fundamentals of Computation Theory](http://www.informatik.uni-trier.de/%7Eley/db/conf/fct/index.html)
- LATIN, [Latin American Symposium on Theoretical Informatics](http://www.latintcs.org/)
- SOFSEM, [Conference on Current Trends in Theory and Practice of Computer Science](http://www.sofsem.cz/)
- TASE, [Theoretical Aspects of Software engineering](http://tase2017.unice.fr)

**CC: COMPLEXITY**

- CCC, [IEEE Conference on Computational Complexity](http://computationalcomplexity.org/)
- SIROCCO, [International Colloquium on Structural Information and Communication Complexity](http://sirocco2013.di.unisa.it/)

**CG: COMPUTATIONAL GEOMETRY**

- SOCG, [Symposium on Computational Geometry](http://www.socg.org/)
- CCCG, [Canadian Conference on Computational Geometry](http://www.cccg.ca/)
- EuroCG, [European Workshop on Computational Geometry](http://eurocg.org/)

**CR: CRYPTOGRAPHY AND SECURITY**

- CRYPTO, [International Cryptology Conference](http://www.iacr.org/conferences/)
- EUROCRYPT, [Conference on the Theory and Applications of Cryptographic Techniques](http://www.iacr.org/conferences/)
- ASIACRYPT, [Conference on the Theory and Application of Cryptology](http://www.iacr.org/conferences/)
- LATINCRYPT, [International Conference on Cryptology and Information Security in Latin America](http://latincrypt2014.labsec.ufsc.br)
- AFRICACRYPT, [International Conference on Cryptology in Africa](http://www.math.unicaen.fr/%7Enitaj/Africacrypt.html)
- PQCRYPTO, [International Conference on Post-Quantum Cryptography](https://2017.pqcrypto.org/conference/)
- TCC, [Theory of Cryptography Conference](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/%7Etcc/)
- PKC, [International Conference on Practice and Theory in Public Key Cryptography](http://www.iacr.org/meetings/pkc/)
- FSE, [Conference on Fast Software Encryption](http://iacr.org/meetings/fse/)
- CHES, [Conference on Cryptographic Hardware and Embedded Systems](http://iacr.org/meetings/ches/)
- IEEE S&P, [IEEE Symposium on Security and Privacy](http://www.ieee-security.org/TC/SP-Index.html)
- CCS,  [ACM Conference on Computer and Communication Security](http://www.sigsac.org/ccs/CCS2011/)
- POST, [Principles of Security and Trust](http://www.etaps.org/2014/post-2014)
- CSF, [Computer Security Foundations Symposium](http://www.ieee-security.org/CSFWweb/)
- ITC, [Information Theoretic Cryptography](https://itcrypto.github.io/2020.html)

**DB: DATABASE THEORY**

- SIGMOD/PODS, [ACM Symposium on Principles of Database Systems](http://www.sigmod.org/sigmod-pods-conferences) (both accept theory, but SIGMOD has broader scope)
- ICDT, [The international Conference on Database Theory](http://icdt.tu-dortmund.de/)
- VLDB, [Very Large Data Bases](http://www.vldb.org/conference.html)
- AMW, [Alberto Mendelzon International Workshop on Foundations of Data Management](http://amw13.cs.buap.mx/)

**DC: DISTRIBUTED, PARALLEL, AND CLUSTER COMPUTING**

- PODC, [ACM Symposium on Principles of Distributed Computing](http://www.podc.org/)
- DISC, [International Symposium on Distributed Computing](http://www.disc-conference.org/)
- SPAA, [ACM Symposium on Parallelism in Algorithms and Architectures](http://www.spaa-conference.org/)
- IPDPS, [IEEE International Parallel and Distributed Processing Symposium](http://www.ipdps.org/)
- ICDCN, [International Conference on Distributed Computing and Networking](http://www.icdcn.org/)
- OPODIS, [International Conference on Principles of Distributed Systems](http://www.opodis.net/)
- SSS, [International Symposium on Stabilization, Safety, and Security of Distributed Systems](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/conferences/sss2012/)
- Algosensors, [International Symposium on Algorithms for Sensor Systems, Wireless Ad Hoc Networks and Autonomous Mobile Entities](http://www.algosensors.org/)

**DM: DISCRETE MATHEMATICS AND COMBINATORICS**

- WG, [International Workshop on Graph-Theoretic Concepts in Computer Science](http://www.informatik.uni-rostock.de/wg2013/)
- LAGOS, [Latin-American Algorithms, Graphs and Optimization Symposium](http://xamanek.izt.uam.mx/LAGOS2013/)

**DS: DATA STRUCTURES AND ALGORITHMS**

- SODA, [ACM-SIAM Symposium on Discrete Algorithms](http://www.siam.org/meetings/archives.php#SODA)
- ESA, [European Symposium on Algorithms](http://esa-symposium.org/) (track A is theoretical)
- WADS, [The Algorithms and Data Structures Symposium](http://www.wads.org/)
- SAT, [Theory and Applications of Satisfiability Testing](http://sat2013.cs.helsinki.fi/)
- SWAT, [Scandinavian Symposium and Workshops on Algorithm Theory](http://swat2012.helsinki.fi/)
- ALENEX, [Algorithm Engineering and Experimentation](http://www.siam.org/meetings/alenex13/)
- SOSA, [Symposium on Simplicity in Algorithms](https://simplicityalgorithms.wixsite.com/sosa)
- IPCO, [Integer Programming and Combinatorial Optimization](http://www.opt.math.tu-graz.ac.at/IPCO/)
- APPROX/RANDOM, [Workshop on Approximation Algorithms for Optimization Problems / Workshop on Randomization and Computation](http://cui.unige.ch/tcs/random-approx/)
- WAOA, [Workshop on Approximation and Online Algorithms](http://www.csd.uwo.ca/waoa/)
- IPEC, [International Symposium on Parameterized and Exact Computation](https://algo2017.ac.tuwien.ac.at/ipec/)
- IWOCA, [International Workshop on Combinatorial Algorithms](https://carma.newcastle.edu.au/meetings/iwoca/)
- WAW, [Workshop on Algorithms and Models for the Web-Graph](http://www.math.ryerson.ca/waw2013/)
- CPM, [Combinatorial Pattern Matching](http://www.cpm2013.de/)
- CP, [Principles and Practice of Constraint Programming](http://cp2013.a4cp.org/)

**FL: AUTOMATA THEORY AND FORMAL LANGUAGES**

- DLT, [International Conference on Developments in Language Theory](http://www.math.utu.fi/projects/dlt/)
- LATA, [Language and Automata Theory and Applications](http://grammars.grlmc.com/lata2013/)
- AFL, [Automata and Formal Languages](http://www.nyf.hu/afl11/)
- NCMA, [Non-Classical Models of Automata and Applications](http://ncma2013.cs.umu.se/)
- CIAA, [International Conference on Implementation and Application of Automata](http://tln.li.univ-tours.fr/ciaa/)
- DFCS, [Descriptional Complexity of Formal Systems](http://www.csd.uwo.ca/dcfs2013/)
- AUTOMATA, [International Workshop on Cellular Automata and Discrete Complex Systems](https://automata2024.webspace.durham.ac.uk/)

**GT: ALGORITHMIC GAME THEORY**

- EC, [Electronic Commerce](http://www.sigecom.org/events.html)
- SAGT, [International Symposium on Algorithmic Game Theory](http://algo.rwth-aachen.de/sagt2013/)
- WINE, [Workshop on Internet and Network Economics](http://wine13.seas.harvard.edu/)

**LG: LEARNING THEORY**

- COLT, [Conference on Learning Theory](http://www.learningtheory.org/)
- ALT, [Algorithmic Learning Theory](http://www-alg.ist.hokudai.ac.jp/%7Ethomas/ALTARCH/altarch.jhtml)

**LO: LOGIC IN COMPUTER SCIENCE**

- LICS, [IEEE Symposium on Logic in Computer Science](http://lii.rwth-aachen.de/lics/)
- CONCUR, [International Conference on Concurrency Theory](http://www.concur-conferences.org/)
- CSL, [Computer Science Logic](http://www.eacsl.org/conferences.html/)
- CiE, [Computablility in Europe](http://www.amsta.leeds.ac.uk/cie/)
- LCC, [An International Workshop on Logic and Computational Complexity](http://ptmat.fc.ul.pt/lcc2012/)
- WoLLIC, [Workshop on Logic, Language, Information and Computation](http://mol-wollic2017.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/wollic2017)
- [Highlights of logic, games and automata](http://highlights-conference.org/)

**PL: PROGRAMMING LANGUAGES**

- POPL, [Principles of Programming Languages](http://popl.mpi-sws.org/)
- ICFP, [International Conference on Functional Programming](http://icfpconference.org/)
- ETAPS, [European Joint Conferences on Theory and Practice of Software](http://www.etaps.org/) (includes FOSSACS, ESOP and POST, see separate entries)
- ESOP, [European Symposium On Programming](https://etaps.org/2022/esop)
- MSFP, Mathematically Structured Functional Programming
- MFPS, Mathematical Foundations of Programming Semantics

**SC: SYMBOLIC COMPUTATION**

- ISSAC: [International Symposium on Symbolic and Algebraic Computation](http://www.issac-conference.org/)
- FPSAC: [Formal Power Series and Algebraic Combinatorics](http://www.fpsac.org/)
- CASC: [Computer Algebra in Scientific Computing](http://www14.in.tum.de/CASC2014/)
- SNC: [Symbolic Numeric Computation](http://symbolic-numeric-computation.org/)

**THEOREM PROVING**

- CADE, [International Conference on Automated Deduction](http://www.cade-24.info/)
- ITP, [Interactive Theorem Proving](http://itp2013.inria.fr/)
- CPP, [Certified Proofs and Programs](http://formes.asia/cpp/)

**QUANTUM**

- QIP, [Workshop on Quantum Information Processing](http://www.qipworshop.org/)
- QCMC, [International Conference on Quantum Communication, Information and Computing](http://www.qcmc2012.org/)
- TQC, [Theory of Quantum Computation, Communication and Cryptography](http://www.uoguelph.ca/quigs/tqc2013/)
- AQIS, [Asian Quantum Information Science Conference](http://www.imsc.res.in/%7Eaqis13/)
- QCRYPT, [Conference on Quantum Cryptography](http://www.qcrypt.net/)
- QEC, [International Conference on Quantum Error Correction](http://qserver.usc.edu/qec11/)
- CEQIP, [Central European Quantum Information Processing Workshop](http://ceqip.eu/)

**RO: Robotics**

- WAFR, [Workshop on the Algorithmic Foundation of Robotics](http://www.wafr.org/).

**COMPUTATIONAL BIOLOGY**

- RECOMB: [Research in Computational Molecular Biology](http://recomb.org/)
- ISMB: [Intelligent Systems for Molecular Biology](http://www.iscb.org/about-ismb)
- WABI: [Workshop on Algorithms in Bioinformatics](http://algo2013.inria.fr/wabi.shtml)

**OTHER**

- CAV, [Computer Aided Verification](http://cav2013.forsyte.at/)
- GD, [International Symposium on Graph Drawing](http://graphdrawing.org/)
- FUN, [International Conference on Fun With Algorithms](http://www.dsi.unive.it/%7Efun2012/)
- DNA, DNA Computing and Molecular Programming (DNA computing, Track A is theoretical, track B is experimental)
- DCM, [Developments in Computational Models](http://www.dcm-workshop.org.uk/)
- RTA, [Rewriting techniques and applications](http://rewriting.loria.fr/rta/)
- TLCA, [Typed lambda calculi and applications](http://www.mimuw.edu.pl/tlca/)
- UCNC, [Unconventional Computation & Natural Computation](http://www.univ-orleans.fr/lifo/events/UCNC2012/index.php)
- RC, [Reversible Computation](https://rc2024.mat.umk.pl/)

Comment: i added learning but for some strange reason cannot get it to format properly

Comment: @Lev: You need to add two blank spaces at the end of a line to produce a carriage return.

Comment: After over a year with this site, I somehow hadn't run into this. Thanks!

Comment: For some ideas: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_science_conferences

Comment: Added ICDT and removed my answer.

Comment: I added the followings and removed my answer (as Jukka Suomela suggested): FSTTCS, ISAAC, LATIN, MFCS, TAMC, WADS, SWAT, ALENEX, EC, SAGT, WINE, SIROCCO, ICDCN, IPCO, APPROX-RANDOM, WAOA, WAW.

Comment: added AQIS below quantum computation

Comment: also added LATA under general

Comment: For PL, MSFP (not MFPS) is a workshop of ICFP, not a conference itself. (There are lots more PL/TCS workshops that we could include too.) To label ICFP as TCS is a bit of a stretch, though. Similarly with POPL, but since it's The Big One, it's not as ostensible.

Comment: Wonder if QCRYPT should be Quantum and/or Crypto…

Comment: IMHO, WG is a good candidate to begin populating the DM section

Comment: Shouldn't GD be in the computational geometry section?

Comment: I think conferences in Other should be moved to their corresponding sections, also it is not clear for me if all of the conferences in General section are really general.

Comment: @Loïck: the [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/corr/subjectclasses) tag that the preprints of their papers are submitted to as their main tag. If a considerable fraction of them (say over 70 percent) use the same main tag that should be where it is placed.

Comment: I didn't move it back to Other, but DNA does not belong in computational biology. Its field is biological computation, which is not the same thing. For GD and WG, we could add an Algorithmic Graph Theory category I suppose.

Comment: @Aaron, maybe we should have a cs.NE category. btw, isn't AGT subset of cs.GT?

Comment: I am worried now that I see ICML and NIPS listed under learning theory, as they don't even claim to be theory conferences.  Makes me wonder whether the rest of the list has similar problems...

Comment: Are RECOMB and ISMB relevant conferences for theory? My impression is that RECOMB is more geared towards tools and applications, while ISMB kind of expects biological results. In general, theoretical work in computational biology looks more like applications than theory for a theory person.

Comment: @Jouni (and Lev): If a conference has both theory and applied papers, it seems appropriate to list.  I don't know anything about the specific conferences you name.  Do any TCS papers appear there?  Maybe more to the point for me personally, do you think discussion of those conferences would be on-topic for the CSTheory Community Blog?

Comment: @Kaveh: By AGT do you mean "Algorithmic Graph Theory" or "Algorithmic Game Theory?"  Either way, I agree with what I think you are saying, which is that we should stick as close to ArXiv tags as possible.  Also, I don't know any theory conference that I would comfortably place in cs.NE -- DNA is not in that category; NE is for neural nets, genetic algorithms, swarm computing, etc.  I have looked at some such conferences, and they all seem application-oriented.

Comment: A good conference in databases is [VLDB](http://www.vldb.org/conference.html) (Very Large Databases). Not sure it's a theoretical conference, though.

Comment: @Jouni RECOMB is very algorithmic. ISMB is less so, but theoretical researchers in comp. bio will publish in both places.

Comment: @Janoma vLDB is not theoretical: it's a big-tent DB conference like STOC or FOCS that also has theory papers in it sometimes. But since PODS and ICDT exist, there's no need to list VLDB

Comment: @Aaron Lev I think ICML/NIPS is borderline, but NIPS is closer to theory than ICML is. To answer Aaron's question, *some* discussions of these conferences would be relevant, but not all.

Comment: @Suresh Aaron, ICML/NIPS are machine learning conferences. They take papers that contribue to ML, and occasionally those papers are theory papers.  But, heck, even SIGCOMM sometimes takes theory papers. The easiest way to see ICML/NIPS aren't theory conferences is that http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1536424 wouldn't appear at either (but could certainly appear at COLT/ALT), even though it's clearly a great learning theory paper. Also, IMO, the reason NIPS is more theory than ICML is b/c the ICML deadline coincides w/ the COLT one, and not by design. My guess is RECOMB is equally not theory.

Comment: @Lev: My two cents: take the conferences out if you think it is that clear.  If someone else wants to edit them back in, that person can provide reasons they should be included.

Comment: Could editors please give justification for their edits?  Someone just removed AfricaCrypt from the list, without giving a reason.  Is it (a) not a conference, or (b) not a TCS conference?

Comment: @Aaron: probably worth reverting.

Comment: I reverted it. By all indications it's a TCS conference. As someone mentioned above the purpose of the list isn't to rank conferences. I also think it's cool to include the CRYPTO conference from each continent.

Comment: @Aaron, are we going to list ALL TCS conferences? I think they are too many of them (you know, there are even conferences that have no expert PC and no expert publishes in them). So I think some criteria of quality and [notability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Notability) is required (it doesn't mean ranking conferences). It seems to me that the user who removed that entry is an expert in crypto (you can check [the question he/she has answered](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/686/user686)), so I think it would be better if people only add entries in their own areas, (more)

Comment: and we should remove the AfricaCrypt unless someone in crypto provides an argument for its noteworthiness.

Comment: @Kaveh: Sure, I would like a list of all TCS conferences.  I would enjoy it if someone blogged from AfricaCrypt. Let's not turn this into an argument about noteworthiness. The list has almost stabilized.

Comment: @Aaron: If you really want to cover everything, perhaps we should add OPODIS, SSS, and Algosensors (category DC)?

Comment: @Jukka: I think SSS is definitely TCS. I don't know anything about the other two.

Comment: @Aaron, IMHO, such a list is useless and practically impossible to create, there are several hundreds (if not thousands or tens of thousands) of TCS conferences and workshops.

Comment: @Kavah: A simple way to deal with the issue could be this: you are only allowed to add conferences/workshops that you actually know "in person": you have participated in the conference, or you have co-authored a paper that was presented at the conference, or you have been involved in conference committees, etc. This way we would only need to list the conferences that are relevant to at least one member of our community.

Comment: FoSSaCS is not specialized in programming languages; ESOP (also part of ETAPS) is.

Comment: AFRICACRYPT should be removed. On, e.g., MS Academic [ http://goo.gl/00hQo ], it is ranked 76th. Crypto, EUROCRYPT and ASIACRYPT are all top 10. Since it the title includes security, IEEE CSF should be included, as well as perhaps IEEE Symposium on Security and Privacy which has a tolerance for theory-oriented papers.

Comment: I removed Africacrypt (again.) Yes, this is a conference that accepts papers about cryptography. But it is a 4th-tier conference that accepts papers about cryptography. (If you insist on including it, then at least 10 other crypto conferences should be listed too.)

Comment: @Dominic Mulligan: Thank you for the theorem proving edits.  That is an area of theory I know nothing about.  As long as you are adding them, perhaps I could ask you to do a little more???  Could you add them also to the conference calendar link in the answer below?  If they don't appear in confsearch.org, you can add the conference to their database. I did that myself with the DNA Computing conference.

Comment: Would add SIGMOD and VLDB to DB.

Comment: About my edit: I saw some "lesser" conferences like Latincrypt and therefore added higher quality conferences like CHES, FSE, PKC, but also for instance Africacrypt (again, as I just noticed). Perhaps a hidden note at the start of the post to clarify what should and should not be in this list would help.

Comment: RTA & TLCA are now combined into FSCD.

Comment: Track C (networks) of Icalp no longer exists.

Comment: Can you also add a bit of a ranking?

Answer (score 17):

**[Conference calendar](https://confsearch.ethz.ch/confsearch/faces/pages/topic.jsp;jsessionid=4664B23ED834C2AEA057E7AFBC4667FA?topic=Theory&sortMode=1&graphicView=1)** by [confsearch](https://confsearch.ethz.ch/confsearch/)
(missing: AMW, MFPS, FPSAC, ITCS, QCRYPT, DCM).

Comment: The list of conferences is copied from the other answer; whenever you add conferences, please edit the URL, too.

Comment: And please keep in mind that confsearch.org is a wiki; *you* can add missing information there...

Comment: confsearch.org also has a category "Theory" where you can view all Theory conferences and add those that are missing http://www.confsearch.org/confsearch/faces/pages/topic.jsp?topic=Theory&sortMode=1&graphicView=1

Comment: Hi Link seems to be broken.

Answer (score 3):

This [list of conferences](http://community.dur.ac.uk/tom.friedetzky/conf.html) by Tom Friedetzky and Daniel Paulusma is another nice resource.

Answer (score 3):

This [list of upcoming cs events](https://cstheory-events.org/list-of-events/) is very practical, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

[Links to Combinatorial Conferences](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~west/meetlist.html)

[Theory Conference](http://confsearch.ethz.ch/confsearch/faces/pages/staticresults.jsp?query=stoc%20focs%20soda%20ec%20swat%20wads%20ics%20podc%20spaa%20icalp%20esa%20ciac%20tamc%20stacs%20isaac%20wg%20random%20approx%20waoa%20socg%20colt&sortMode=1&graphicView=1)