# Are there websites for TCS announcements that maintain mailing-lists  or web feeds?

Tags: soft-question, conferences

For a while, I have been wondering if there exists some site where you can subscribe to receive TCS-conference announcements via e-mail, or, alternatively, that offers some periodically-updated *[web-feed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_feed#Confusion_between_Web_feed_and_RSS)*. This is obviously very useful, but I have been unable to find one myself. Does anyone know of some reliable options?

Two examples of what I had in mind, which I use to look for conferences in *quantum information/quantum physics* and to keep track of their deadlines.

- [Quantum Meetings](http://qserver.usc.edu/confs/), has a RSS channel.
- QUROPE, for European events, has a [mailing list](http://qurope.eu/user).

Related posts: [List of TCS conferences and workshops](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7900/list-of-tcs-conferences-and-workshops).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [dmanet](http://www.zaik.uni-koeln.de/mailman/listinfo/dmanet) is one of a good sites for this, it also emails open positions for job and education in CS. But it's good for Europe.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check the [theorynet](https://listserv.nodak.edu/cgi-bin/wa.exe?A0=THEORYNT) mailing list for CS theory related announcements. I believe there are several lists for specific communites, for example, for distributed computing there is the [PODC](http://www.podc.org/podc-mailinglist.txt) list.

Comment: I do not see specific lists... but I can certainly try the main one.

Answer (score 1):

Different sections of the arxiv have their own RSS feeds for paper announcement, or you can subscribe to the [theory aggregator](http://feedworld.net/toc/) (for ECCC/arxiv/blogs)

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that. I was --maybe I wasn't the only-- opening it manually every day.