# List of TCS conferences along with important dates

Tags: soft-question, big-list, conferences

I saw that there is a post with a [List of TCS conferences](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7900/list-of-tcs-conferences-and-workshops). However, this does not list important dates like conference date, submission deadline etc. Is there any post or website which maintains these information and also keeps it up-to-date?

Comment: See [this answer](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/7904/186).

Comment: @Kaveh, even though it's a bit of a repeat, I think it's worth making that a proper answer, confsearch is fantastic (imho) and answers this question precisely.

Comment: It's the second answer on the linked question. Seems like a duplicate to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of TCS conferences and workshops](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7900/list-of-tcs-conferences-and-workshops)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm maintaining such a list here:
https://sites.google.com/site/yixincaoresearch/conferences.

Thanks due to  Anupam Gupta and Iftah Gamzu.

Comment: This appears to no longer exist.

Comment: It's no longer available.  A very maintained one can be found at http://community.dur.ac.uk/tom.friedetzky/conf.html.

Answer (score 2):

Miki Hermann maintains such a list, and keeps it very much up-to-date:

http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/Labo/Miki.Hermann/conf.html