# How to find interesting algorithms to implement?

Tags: ds.algorithms, soft-question

I am not a researcher in algorithms (I am a college freshman).
I would like to implement an interesting recent algorithm from 
a data structure/algorithms paper.

How can find a good algorithms paper to implement?

Comment: I'm afraid this is both too subjective and too broad. Basically, why couldn't you pick any paper you like?

Comment: I couldn't because i am not sure where to look, my professor has given me a constraint to pick newer(>2012) papers from data structure and algorithms. What i am looking for is some pointers, as to where to start looking or a good list of papers to select from

Comment: Tarjan just published this at SODA, should be accessible to an undergrad. http://www.madalgo.au.dk/img/SS2013/Course%20material/H-DisjointSetUnionWithRandomizedLinkingMS_Tarjan.pdf

Comment: look at the proceedings of algorithms conferences (see the question http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/7900/4896), find a paper you understand enough to implement

Comment: I believe many researchers will be very happy if a person comes and implements their recently-developed algorithm. Some of them may even help you understand their algorithm so that you can implement it better. Maybe you should go to a nearby university and put a note on the message board of the CS department? This may also lead you to fruitful cooperations in the future.

Comment: the main site does not allow questions similar to "what should I work on" maybe with good reason (meta posts address/reject this type of question). however it seems a common request & would like to see some support for it here eg maybe meta to help with broader promotion of TCS. also try cs.se

Comment: Maybe you could be more specific about what kinds of algorithms you're looking for? Many algorithms proposed in theoretical CS are quite easy (trivial?) to implement; the tricky part is the proof. I am thinking in particular of Buchbinder, Feldman, Naor, and Schwartz's 2012 "A Tight Linear Time (1/2)-Approximation For Unconstrained Submodular Maximiztion", an algorithm from The Book if there ever was one. http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~moranfe/Publications/FOCS2012.pdf

Comment: Requests for project subjects are [off-topic, here](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/802/policy-questions-about-topic-for-research-project).

Comment: I edited the question to make it on-topic by changing it from asking for the papers to how to find such papers.

Comment: @usul _Many algorithms proposed in theoretical CS are quite easy (trivial?) to implement_ — On the other hand, many algorithms proposed in theoretical CS are _nearly impossible_ to implement.