# What are good conferences for algorithms about finite automata?

Tags: graph-algorithms, automata-theory, dfa, finite-model-theory, analysis-of-algorithms

I am writing a research paper, which describes some properties about finite automata. It also provides a couple of algorithms that can measure some aspects of the properties.

Could you point out some related conferences that this topic can well fit? And how good they are?

Comment: possible duplicate of [List of TCS conferences and workshops](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7900/list-of-tcs-conferences-and-workshops)

Comment: Your question is too imprecise. What kind of finite automata are you considering (deterministic or not, one or two ways, with or without output, working on finite words, infinite words, trees, etc.)? Do your automata occur in a specific context (verification, learning, linguistics, etc.)? What kind of properties are you interested in?

Comment: @j-e-pin is right. Context matters. I would suggest the Southeastern Conference but the deadline was 5 days ago. http://math.fau.edu/cgtc/

Answer (score 6):

The main conferences where automata are among the main topics are ICALP, LICS, STACS, CSL, MFCS, FSTTCS.

If you feel your paper is not strong enough for these conferences (which accept about a quarter of the papers that are sent each year), you can send to conferences which are a little less exigeant.

The ICALP submission deadline is soon (in a week), after this the next in the list is FSTTCS I believe.

These conferences are all european (except FSTTCS from India), it seems that automata are less popular in USA, but it might be that your results interest some people at STOC or FOCS.

Comment: What about CIAA ?

Comment: didn't know this one, the list I gave might not be complete. What is the approximate level?

Comment: it seems to be about implementation and application, so not too much on the theoretical side.

Comment: It is written "The CIAA conferences concern research on all aspects of implementation and application of automata and related structures, including theoretical aspects. "

Comment: it is also ranked C here, so it would be an option for not very strong papers: http://lipn.univ-paris13.fr/~bennani/CSRank.html

Comment: Beware: that list is based on an Australian ranking from 2006-8, and has absurdities like ranking CSL as a C (nowadays B if not A), and giving highish rankings to various Australasian regional conferences.

Comment: Actually CIAA is ranked B.  There is a different conference, with the same acronym, that is ranked C.