# Some good Theoretical Computer Science Journals

Tags: soft-question, research-practice, paper-review, journals

I have been doing some work in Theoretical Computer Science(especially related to algorithms), and I wanted the publish some of my findings. Can someone please suggest some good journals or publications in the same area.

Comment: If your paper is in a publishable state, it will contain a discussion of related papers. You can simply check where these papers (and the references that they cite) have been published that should give you some ideas.

Comment: Most TCS work is (initially at least) published in conferences. For conferences, two primary ones are the Symposium on Theory of Computing (STOC) and Foundations of Computer Science (FOCS); there are many more, some of which are more specialized. Symposium on Discrete Algorithms (SODA), International Colloquium on Automata, Languages, and Programming (ICALP), Innovations in Theoretical Computer Science (ITCS). See the question [list of tcs conferences and workshops](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7900/list-of-tcs-conferences-and-workshops).

Comment: Let me just point that some scientists boycotting the journals of Elsevier. Here is the related website: http://thecostofknowledge.com

Comment: [Microsoft ranking of TCS journals](http://academic.research.microsoft.com/RankList?entitytype=4&topdomainid=2&subdomainid=1&last=0) (YMMV)

Answer (score 6):

Apart from top conferences mentioned by @usul, I think Journal of the ACM (JACM) is a top journal in computer science, which also includes many excellent theoretical computer science papers. In addition, I read some papers published in [Algorithmica](http://www.springer.com/computer/theoretical+computer+science/journal/453). Also, just giving a reference, I find a link to some journals related to Discrete Mathematics (particularly refer to Theoretical Computer Science and Algorithms part), see http://www.math.iit.edu/~kaul/Journals.html.

Comment: The SIAM Journal on Computing (SICOMP) is also popular.